# Update a flot chart using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, flot

I created a wheight chart using flot plugin and I do :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var data1 = [
    [gd(2012, 0, 1), 67],
    [gd(2012, 1, 1), 68],
    [gd(2012, 2, 1), 75],
    [gd(2012, 3, 1), 69]
];

var data2 = [
    [gd(2012, 0, 1), 60],
    [gd(2012, 1, 1), 60],
    [gd(2012, 2, 1), 60],
    [gd(2012, 3, 1), 60]
];
var dataset = [{
    label: "weight",
    data: data1
}, {
    label: "Goal weight",
    data: data2
}];

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            radius: 3,
            fill: true,
            show: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [5, "day"],
        tickLength: 0,
        axisLabel: "2013",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 10
    },
    yaxes: [{
        axisLabel: "",
        axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
        axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
        axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
        axisLabelPadding: 3,
        tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
            return $.formatNumber(v, {
                format: "#,###",
                locale: "us"
            });
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        noColumns: 0,
        labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
        position: "nw"
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "#633200",
        backgroundColor: {
            colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"]
        }
    },
    colors: ["#FFA100", "#B7C84B"]
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder1"), dataset, options);
    $("#flot-placeholder1").UseTooltip();
});

function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
}

var previousPoint = null,
    previousLabel = null;
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];


$.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
    $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                previousLabel = item.series.label;
                $("#tooltip").remove();

                var x = item.datapoint[0];
                var y = item.datapoint[1];

                var color = item.series.color;
                var month = new Date(x).getDay();

                //console.log(item);

                if (item.seriesIndex == 0) {
                    showTooltip(item.pageX,
                        item.pageY,
                        color,
                        "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + monthNames[month] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>(USD)");
                } else {
                    showTooltip(item.pageX,
                        item.pageY,
                        color,
                        "<strong>" + item.series.label + "</strong><br>" + monthNames[month] + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>(%)");
                }
            }
        } else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
};

function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        display: 'none',
        top: y - 40,
        left: x - 120,
        border: '2px solid ' + color,
        padding: '3px',
        'font-size': '9px',
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
        opacity: 0.9
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}
```

});

what I need exactly :

1- putting the data in a separate file, for example ajax.json :

```
var data1 = [
[gd(2012, 0, 1), 67],
[gd(2012, 1, 1), 68],
[gd(2012, 2, 1), 75],
[gd(2012, 3, 1), 69]
];

var data2 = [
[gd(2012, 0, 1), 60],
[gd(2012, 1, 1), 60],
[gd(2012, 2, 1), 60],
[gd(2012, 3, 1), 60]
];
```

because I'll get values from database but I don't know how to do with the function gd() :

```
function gd(year, month, day) {
    return new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
}
```

2- the second issue is that I hope to refresh the chart to update data.I tried but everytime I get error and the chart just disappearing,my idea is to use ajax with click function :

```
$("button.dataUpdate").click(function () {

....

function onDataReceived() {

    $.plot("#flot-placeholder1", data, options);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: onDataReceived
});
```

so I tried to run ajax by clicking "dataupdate" buttton then I get data from ajax.json page and finally update and refreshing the chart?Any I idea?

**Remark : Please I spent 2 days to find a solution to integrate the last code correctly in my first code to get all works so please I hope a direct solution with code not just a comment...**

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that wall of code.

Comment: That attitude is an interesting approach to encourage random strangers on the internet to give you free help.

Comment: [Definition of __irony__ at Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irony)

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you try to refresh the chart? Please copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just some general tips: If you're stuck on something for a long time, try to spend some time, maybe a few days to a week learning about AJAX, flot, JSON, etc. and then come back to your problem with all that new knowledge you have. Also, you should try checking your code against automatic code-checkers such as [jshint.com](http://jshint.com).

Here are some errors I detected using JSHint which might be causing your problems. Please comment if your code still doesn't work.

```
Line 1: $(document).ready(function () {
Unmatched '{'.

Line 136: }
Expected ')' and instead saw ''.

Line 136: }
Missing semicolon.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem lies with not doing anything within the "onDataReceived" function to renew the data. The code within this function should look more like this:

```
function onDataReceived(series) {
    data = []; // Delete this line if you want to add graphs, not replace them.
    data.push(series);
    $.plot("#flot-placeholder1", data, options);
}
```

This should give you a working example with data on the page you're requesting looking like this:

```
"label": "Label Name",
"data": [[1999, 3.0], [2000, 3.9], [2001, 2.0], [2002, 1.2], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]]
```

Your last problem is the "gd" function you are trying to use. You are asking for a JSON response in your code, and then are trying to parse the JSON data. Only gd() is not recognized as such.

For more info turn to their ajax example, and look at the source code: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/

Good luck!

EDIT: Instead of using the gd() function, just use a unix timestamp (multiplied with 1000 for javascript purposes). It works like a charm.